# Making a Command Reply with a Mentioned User

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a hug command. I want it to be used like "/hugs @user" and the bot replies with "@author sent a hug to @user!". When I use the code below, I just set it to try to reply with the mentioned user but it doesn't work. I have tried setting it to a variable as well and putting "message.mentions.users.first()" in a variable too. It seems to work for other people after what I've looked up but for some reason nothing is working for me. The bot does not reply at all after mentioning a user. No errors pop up either.

```
    if (words == `${prefix}hugs`) {
        message.channel.send(`<@${message.mentions.users.first().id}>`);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (words == `${prefix}hugs`) {
    message.channel.send(`${message.author} sent a hug to ${message.mentions.members.first()}`);
}
```

You don't have to get the id, you can just use the member. It will return the first member mentioned in the message.

Comment: Yeah I tried that already and it doesn't work. The bot still doesn't reply at all and there's no error messages.

Comment: Your issue is most likely your command handler then, what does that look like?

Comment: The command handler is a different part of the code that doesn't affect this part honestly. I'm not making this as a separate command I figured it would be easier to do this as just a side thing within the client function. Does that only work as a command?

Comment: I believe the issue here could be that your command is not being detected whatsoever. Meaning, when you are entering the command in discord, the bot doesn't see it which is why it's not sending a message back. Try `if(message.content) === \`${prefix}hugs\``.

Comment: Sorry I already figured out the problem a couple days ago. It was because it wasn't a command file it was just placed in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

So the code works when made as a command file but for some reason only one person is allowed to use the command. I've deleted the file and rewrote it, changed the name, and everything. That was why i ended up putting it in the main function since it for some reason only lets one user use the command. It seems like the first person who used it originally is the only person allowed to use it. Is there a way to erase that memory or something since it might've been from previous code that was messed up?

Here's my new current code

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'hug',
    description: 'Used to hug everyone or mention a user to hug them specifically.',
    execute(message,args) {
        args = message.mentions.users.size;

        if (!args) {
            message.delete();
            return message.channel.send(`${message.author} gives a big ol' hug to everyone!`);
        }
        else {
            message.delete();
            return message.channel.send(`${message.author} sends love to ${message.mentions.users.first()} with a hug!`);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Turns out it's not just this command. All commands can only be used by one person right now. I guess a variable saved their ID somewhere as the only person that can run the command and didn't reset to be empty.